# Adding a new column by multiplying two columns from different dataframes with the same index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two indexed dataframes:

total_data

```
                       quantity
customer brand product
      C1    B1      P1      100
      C1    B1      P2       10
      C1    B2      P3       50
      C2    B1      P1       75
      C2    B2      P3        5
```

and products:

```
                 price
brand product
   B1      P1        5
   B1      P2       20
   B2      P3        7
```

when I print `total_data.quantity * products.price` I get this:

```
                       quantity
customer brand product
      C1    B1      P1      500
      C1    B1      P2      200
      C1    B2      P3      350
      C2    B1      P1      375
      C2    B2      P3       35
```

But I want to assign this column to `total_data`
So, I tried two methods:

`total_data['income'] = total_data.quantity * products.price`

and

`total_data.assign(income = total_data.quantity * products.price)`

But in both cases I got `NaN` values in the `income` column.

Are there solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here how i would combine the data:

```
df = total_data.merge(products, 'left') 
df['income'] = df['quantity'] * df['price']
```

for output:

```
  customer brand product  quantity  price        income
0       C1    B1      P1       100      5           500
1       C1    B1      P2        10     20           200
2       C1    B2      P3        50      7           350
3       C2    B1      P1        75      5           375
4       C2    B2      P3         5      7            35
```

or

```
 total_data['income'] = total_data['quantity'] * total_data.merge(products, 'left')['price']
```

for:

```
  customer brand product  quantity  income
0       C1    B1      P1       100     500
1       C1    B1      P2        10     200
2       C1    B2      P3        50     350
3       C2    B1      P1        75     375
4       C2    B2      P3         5      35
```

Comment: I found another solution already..

The output indexes of `total_data.quantity * products.price` is another than `customer, brand, product`
So I used another construction:

`total_data['income'] = (total_data.quantity * products.price).reorder_levels(['customer', 'brand', 'product'])`